# Keyboard does not appear for TextView from XIB file -- Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

So I have a TextView which is referenced in the .h file from the XIB file . So here the issue is whenever I click on the TextView the keyboard does not appear at all , nothing happens when I click on the textView.

PS - I use a Xcode 8 currently. If i create a build using Xcode 7.3 then the keyboard appears properly. I dont know what goes wrong with Xcode 8.

 I have tried everything , explicitly set the textview delegate as self, enabled the textView , called other delegate methods .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In real device it will show keyboard.

If you are checking in simulator then try:

---- Toggle software keyboard using shortcut is `⌘K` (Command+K).

***OR***

---- Go to `iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard` and Uncheck **"Connect Hardware Keyboard"** or Select **"Toggle Software Keyboard"**

Comment: This happens on device

Answer (score 0):

If keyboard can appear when you run the code with Xcode7, that proved your code is no problem.

The Xcode simulator had a problem for a long time, sometimes may not show the keyboard, but through the shortcut keys can exhale the keyboard, command + K can.

Comment: Yes I tried that too , the problem is with the device . The keyboard doesnt show up on the device

Comment: tell me type and version of your device